# Words length in Faker

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, faker

How to generate array of words of specific length from Faker gem in rails? For example I would like to make an array of five words, where each word's length is also five.

Comment: Are the words allowed to have digits?

Comment: yes. The words may be of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any 5 characters that can mix digits as well as alphabets, maybe this one could help you as well apart from Aliaksei's solution.

```
5.times.map { Faker::Lorem.characters(5) }
```

What it does is it gives you an array of 5 combinations of 5 random characters, that can include any English alphabet in small from `a to z` and any digit from `0 to 9`.

You get something like this.

```
["uw1ep", "04lhs", "0c4d9", "31n1j", "mrspp"]
```

Comment: Thank you @Nabin Paudyal

Comment: how do I do this in javascript library?

Comment: This solution no longer works. The correct syntax is `Faker::Lorem.characters(number: 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Faker::Internet.user_name`](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/doc/default/internet.md) supports length parameter. You can generate 5 random words this way:

```
5.times.map { Faker::Internet.user_name(5..5) }
# => ["uriah", "gabri", "haili", "jewel", "georg"]
```

Another good option is [`Faker::Name.initials`](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/doc/default/name.md) which was introduced in `faker` `v1.8.5`

```
Faker::Name.initials(5)
# => "FPSIR"
```

Comment: Thank you @Aliaksei Kliuchnikau

Answer (score 0):

Updating @Nabin Paudyal's answer for [Faker v2.0](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/releases/tag/2.0) and greater (post 2019-31-07) where the `number:` keyword argument is now required for specifying the (character) length.

```rb
5.times.map { Faker::Lorem.characters(number: 5) }
```

Which gives you something like this...

```rb
["1ktl0", "s9ao5", "d99ij", "uc3us", "37mmm"]
```